# Building a large (18m keys) lookup table in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, tuples

I have many JSON disk files of lists of tuples (JSON stores them as a list of lists of course).

In each list, each tuple is unique and contains two items

However, in different lists, there are tuples where the first item (which is essentially a key) is identical in the different lists, but the second item of the tuple is different.

Example:

```
list_20190101 = [
        ("123456789", "bad_person"),
        ("234567891", "a_person"),
        ("345678912", "b_person"),
        ...
        ]

list_20200101 = [
        ("123456789", "bad_person"),
        ("234567891", "a_person"),
        ("456789123", "c_person"),
        ...
        ]

list_20211010 = [
        ("123456789", "good_person"),
        ("234567891", "a_person"),
        ("345678912", "b_person"),
        ("456789123", "c_person"),
        ("567891234", "d_person"),
        ...
        ]
```

There are about 10.5 thousand of these lists, each with between 1 and 400,000 tuples.
These are distributed rather unevenly: ~90% of the files contain < 5,000 tuples, but perhaps 100 have >100,000.
In total, there are about 54 million tuples, of which about 18 million are unique.

I want to derive a lookup table with an entry for each so I can see for any unique "key", what all the "values" it has taken.
From the three lists above, for instance, something similar to the following dictionary, where any repeated value is only recorded once.

```
{
"123456789": ["good_person", "bad_person"],
"234567891": "a_person",
"345678912": "b_person",
"456789123": "c_person",
"567891234": "d_person",
...
}
```

I've tried using **setdefault** for this:

```
import json

filelist = ["list_20190101.json", "list_20200101.json", "list_20211010.json", ...]
ltable = {}

def get_data(datafile):
    with open(datafile) as d:
        data = json.load(d)

    return data

def combine_data():
    for f in filelist:
        data = get_data(f)
        for i in data:
            ltable.setdefault(i[0], set()).add(i[1].lower())

    return ltable


lookup_table = combine_data()

# then write out lookup_table, probably as JSON.
# though we have to first convert the dict values to lists as json won't serialise sets
```

While this seems to be working OK for smaller test batches, it doesn't seem to scale well: when we try to run on the entire dataset, it gets slower and slower and we relatively quickly start to run out of memory & the process essentially grinds to a halt.

[I've only considered a dictionary/JSON approach because that's what I'm familiar with & it works well for the smaller scale of a few tens (rarely hundreds) of MB of data that I normally work with.]

Constraints:

~ I'm not a professional coder, this is home project, I only know some Python and my skills are very limited
~ The biggest/fastest hardware available is an i7+6GB laptop

Nevertheless this appears to be a pretty straightforward task of a kind that data professionals must deal with all the time.

Note that this is **not** about simply merging these files to create a single dictionary with unique keys: the question is about getting lists (or sets) of multiple values for many of the keys' values.
We *could* exclude from the lookup table items where there is only a single value for the key, but we also need to be able to update the lookup table from fresh data, and k/v pairs which currently only have a single value might need to be updated

So I'm asking what alternative approaches (in Python) that I can try to improve the speed of processing & reduce the memory overhead. Or do I need to head into database (eg sqlite3) territory?

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend doing this in memory. Imo you should use a database push everything there, then add index on the key and query what you need. Also make the id an int while you are at it to save space.

Comment: @rani-sharim I wondered about whether making the key an int might help but the question already seemed to be too long and involved to add that

Comment: If your data does not fit into memory, there is very little what you can do to make it fit. At most you can get some spare change but there aren’t many viable options. So you should take *some* disk-backed intermediate storage - that may be a database, message queue or even raw files. FWIW, one can probably parallelise this easily by having separate processes for each file sorting items into queues for another set of writing processes (basically a bucket sort).

Comment: At first glance I would say that using `set` to check for duplicates is overkill in terms of memory. On my python version 216 bytes are allocated for a `set`. Although I see the motivation I would suggest to store just plain strings in your lookup tables, e.g., something like `"good_person;bad_person"` instead of `{"good_person", "bad_person"}`. Besides, as I understand your set are usually small.